# Arduino error: 'I2C_MODE' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, arduino, seeeduino

I'm making a program where a buzzer activates if the accelerometer is tilted a certain number of degrees. I'm getting an error that says "'I2C_MODE' was not declared in this scope." I'm using a Grove Beginner Kit, so all of the parts are automatically connected to each other. I downloaded Seeed_Arduino_LIS3DHTR library from the following link:  https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeed_Arduino_LIS3DHTR and used sample code from the Grove Beginner Kit for Arduino Guide that came with the board, so everything should work properly. I'm getting this error and don't want to move further with the project until I figure out what's causing this error.

```
#include <LIS3DHTR.h>

//Gravity Acceleration
#include "LIS3DHTR.h"
#ifdef SOFTWAREWIRE
#include <SoftwareWire.h>
SoftwareWire myWire(3, 2);
LIS3DHTR<SoftwareWire> LIS(I2C_MODE); //IIC    This is what the error 
#define WIRE myWire
#else
#include <Wire.h>
LIS3DHTR<TwoWire> LIS(I2C_MODE);//IIC          THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
#define WIRE Wire
#endif
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial) {};
LIS.begin(WIRE); //IIC init
delay(100);
LIS.setOutputDataRate(LIS3DHTR_DATARATE_50HZ);
}
void loop() {
if (!LIS) {
Serial.println("LIS3DHTR didn't connect.");
while (1);
return;
}
//3 axis
Serial.print("x:"); Serial.print(LIS.getAccelerationX()); Serial.prin
t(" ");
Serial.print("y:"); Serial.print(LIS.getAccelerationY()); Serial.prin
t(" ");
Serial.print("z:"); Serial.println(LIS.getAccelerationZ());
delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code. As it stands here it is unreadable.

Comment: If you're using i2c in Arduino, you need the Wire library, and thus the `Wire.h` header file included.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs you linked](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeed_Arduino_LIS3DHTR#usage) have a different instantiation than what you have!

Try passing `Wire` to the `.begin` method rather than to `LIS` (which presumably *does* exist in `Wire.h` and likely also exists in `SoftwareWire.h`)

Plausibly putting `LIS.begin()` in `setup()` is needed, though it doesn't seem to matter from their examples

```
LIS3DHTR<TwoWire> LIS; //IIC
LIS.begin(Wire, 0x19)
```